# How access aws QLDB without passing accesskey and secret key in application?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am deploying an application in eks cluster that will access aws QLDB.
Currently I am passing access key and secret key to access the application.
there is any way we can access the QLDB without using access key.

Comment: What are you using to access QLDB ?

Comment: we have QLDB create in the aws account and we have create IAM user which had full access of db and we are passing  aws accessid and accesskey to application.

Comment: Perhaps adding in some code and specifying the expectation of that code would help here? I'm not sure if you're using the AWS SDK or something else to access QLDB- accordingly, the answers could vary.